# Dynamically change Nagios alert Subject

Tags: dynamic, nagios

We are using `hostescalation` to handle our `notify-host-by-email` escalations. Is it possible to dynamically change the Subject line on these alerts to include the downtime in minutes?

For example: `Host Alert: $HOSTNAME$ is $HOSTSTATE$ for X minutes`

**Edit 1**: just thought of this. Is there an easier way though?

Since my escalation is only to escalate after 20 minutes, I know my downtime is 20 minutes.

1. Create a new `contactgroup`
2. Create a new `contact` in contacts.cfg
3. Create a new `contact template` in templates.cfg
4. Create a new `host_notification_commands` which points to a new `command` in commands.cfg which has the new subject line of "20 minute down time".

It's a little drawn out, but it could work. Surely there's an easier way?

**Edit 2**: This actually doesn't work how I thought it would. The first alert came out with the modified subject line.

So I'm back to the question: Can the subject lines be dynamically modified based on the number of minutes the host has been down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it.

Using `$HOSTDURATION$` in the subject line of the `notify-host-by-email` will quickly tell us how long the host has been down for.

This should do the trick.

More info on this [Nagios Macro here](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/macrolist.html#hostduration).